# How to create dynamic component using parent class input properties

Tags: angular

How to create a **dynamic component** using parent class input properties?

I have multiple chart components, based on user selection I have to load one OR more charts component at runtime. As there are several common input properties for different charts and common functions for the chart click event i.e series/palet click etc. I want to create a parent chart class for all the charts and want to keep the common inputs and common functions here. could somebody please guide how to achieve this **angular 6**

Comment: this might help you 
https://stackblitz.com/angular/baxobjxqrnq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d